# Laravel Conditional route key using getRouteKeyName

Tags: laravel

My primary key on the table is `id`, On the other hand i have a column with name of `slug` and it is nullable, I want to set route key of my model by `slug` **when the slug column filled and not null** otherwise leave it as `id`, I tried these:

```php
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    if ($this->slug) return 'slug';

    return 'id';
}
```

The problem is `$this` returns only instance of model on that method and will not return the current model which involved in the request, I also tried `request()->route('post')` but doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

It probably not the best way, but I would do something like that:

**Route**:

```php
Route::get('/somepath/{variable}', 'SomeController@index');
```

**Controller**:

```php
public function index($variable)
{
    $model = Model::where('slug', $variable)->first();

    if (null === $model) {
        $model = Model::where('id', $variable)->first();
    }

    // other logic
}
```

Comment: Not ideal for REST routes cuz i should done that for every actions.

Comment: you can move model getting into standalone method and use it in construtor